# Can't get JS form working

Tags: javascript, php, email, post

I've been debugging this form for the last two days and I just can't figure out what is going on..! The vars and the form ID's all seem to check in every file but when I upload it..I get the error code of the JS file "Sorry, 'name', there is a problem".

Any ideas?

.HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6  padding-none">
                    <div class="box-white padding-all">
                        <h2 class="title-border right block-mobile">Contact Headquarters</h2>
                        <div class="data-form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="qualform" id="qualform" value="Headquarters">
                            <form action="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                                    <label>Company</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Enter your company" id="company" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                                    <label>Telephone</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your telephone" id="phone" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                                    <label>E-Mail</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-md-12 col-md-12">
                                    <label>Website</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="website" placeholder="Enter your website" id="website">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label>Message</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message" id="message" required></textarea>
                                        <div id="success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">SEND YOUR MESSAGE</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

.JS

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $(".show input#name").val();
            var company = $(".show input#company").val();
            var email = $(".show input#email").val();
            var phone = $(".show input#phone").val();
            var website = $(".show input#website").val();
            var message = $(".show textarea#message").val();
            var qualform = $(".show input#qualform").val();
            var firstName = name; 

            // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '../mail/contact_me.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    company: company,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    website: website,
                    message: message,
                    qualform: qualform,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('.show #success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-success')
                        .append(firstName + ", your e-mail was successfully sent.");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('.show #contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('.show #success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry, " + firstName + ", it seems like there is a problem. Please try again");
                    $('.show #success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('.show #contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('.show #success').html('');
});
```

---

.PHP

```
<?php
// sanitize
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Check for empty fields
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name          = $_POST['name'];
$company       = $_POST['company'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];
$phone         = $_POST['phone'];
$website       = $_POST['website'];
$message       = $_POST['message'];

$to            = 'my.email@email.com';
$email_subject = "Contact from website website ($qualform)";
$email_body    = "New form from $qualform.\n\n" . "User info:\n\nName: $name\n\nCompany: $company\n\nE-mail: $email\n\nTelephone: $phone\n\nWebsite: $website\n\nMessage: $message";
$headers       = "From: Form website <my.email@email.com>\r\n";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
return true;
?>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, check, what is returned by php script (contact_me.php) via browser developer functions - network tab. Then try to set dataType: json for your ajax call, may be it helps

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a value from a variable `$qualform` in your PHP code which doesn't exist, thus it will give you an error (which means a bad status code) which then triggers the error function in your JS.

Try using the network inspector in chrome more, you'll be able to see all inbound and outbound requests with the data that is sent back.

I also advise using a text editor like PHPStorm that highlights syntax errors or unresolved variables and use a debugger like xdebug to pause your code to see what's inside your variables.